# Scala ide recommandation

Tags: ubuntu, apache, scala, netbeans, intellij

I am still new to Apache spark, hdfs and scala. I am starting a new project on Spark. I am using HDFS and Scala. I need an Ide for my scala programming. I know how to use Netbeans but now after doing my research eclipse and Intellij has come up....which one should i use as an IDE for my project using scala. 
Ps: i have scala sbt, but my professor told me i need an Ide to manage large data

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, IntelliJ is the quickest way to get started.

If you already use eclipse regularly and are comfortable with it, you could try it, but intelliJ works as soon as you install the scala plugin.

I agree with your professor.  Once you have a few source files an IDE really helps.  But learning any IDE requires effort so allow a bit of time to learn the features.